# Windows Remote Desktop fails through VPN until browsing to network share

Tags: windows-7, vpn, remote-desktop

I'm using GlobalProtect from Palo Alto to establish a connection to another location. Then I try to use windows remote desktop to a machine (by IP or computer name) and get the following error:

[image: cant connect]
"Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons: ..."

If I browse to a network share on the machine first (by IP, or computer name, asks for credentials), remote desktop will work. I have to do this every time I connect to VPN, although it seems this doesn't always fix the problem. (Trying to troubleshoot this issue right now, I can no longer connect remote desktop).

Any idea how to successfully connect to remote desktop?

windows 7 pro, x64, let me know any other required information.

---

Once I'm connected, everything works fine.

Telnet, before browsing network share:

```
C:\Windows\system32>telnet [ip] 3389
Connecting To [ip] ...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3389 : Connect failed
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the remote machine via name or IP?  If it's by name, try using the RDP host's IP address instead (also try using its FQDN).

Comment: Connect the VPN then try TELNET 10.20.30.40 3389, this should connect you to a black screen. It will demonstrate that the connection is up and the port is available. Frankly what you are describing doesn't make much sense to me. If TELNET fails then its a timing issue. Try the telnet before browsing the share and then after.

Comment: TELNET doesn't work before browsing network share. Remote desktop has stopped connecting (it was fine a minute ago) so I'm not sure about the "after."

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any difference using name or IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to a different router fixed the problem. No idea why.